# Accessing googleapis.google.com gives "No Route To Host"

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We a running a java program on a server which is located at a service-provider location (where we have only limited access to). This program writes data in a GCS bucket and uses the google-cloud-storage library for that.
This usually works fine, but all for a sudden we are getting "No Route To Host googleapis.google.com" exceptions which is obviously a problem within the service-provider network. Unfortunately they don't find the root cause fast, but they suggest a workaround to use "googleapis.l.google.com" instead.
So is there a way to tell the google-cloud-storage lib to use googleapis.l.google.com???

ping googleapis.google.com gives "No Route To Host"
ping googleapis.l.google.com succeeds

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to specify the URL for the Java lib, however you may use rest api calls in order to specify the alternate URL you mentioned, like in this [example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) (REST APIs tab)